# code breaks when used inside custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, materialize

I'm trying to combine angular and the frontend framework materialize, since I find it better than angular-material. The following code works and results in a parallax scrolling sample:

```
<html lang="en">


<head>

  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>

    <script src="angularApp.js"></script>

</head>
        <body ng-app='angularApp'>
         (...)
      <div class="parallax-container">
          <div class="parallax"><img src="http://i3.minus.com/ibdMPM9Oo2TGYu.png" ></div>
      </div>
      <div class="section white">
          <div class="row container">
              <h2 class="header">Parallax</h2>
              <p class="grey-text text-darken-3 lighten-3">Parallax is an effect where the background content or image in this case, is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax-container">
          <div class="parallax"><img src="http://i3.minus.com/ibdMPM9Oo2TGYu.png" ></div>
      </div>    


      </body>
    </html>
```

However, this parallax effect stops working completely when I "refactor" it into a custom directive, like this:

```
 <html lang="en">
        (...)
        <body ng-app='angularApp'>
         (...)
           <hometab></hometab>

          </body>
        </html>
```

///////

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("angularApp", []);


app.directive('hometab', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'hometab.html'

    };
});

})();
```

(hometab.html contains the code that used to be in the main html).

Why is this breaking the code?

Edit: To clarify, by breaking I mean that the code is inserted, but the parallax effect isn't working (I assume the javascript isn't doing its job correctly?)

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Are you by any chance declaring the `angularApp` module more than once? Note that in all the files for your application you should only do this `angular.module("angularApp", []);` once. It declares the module specifying an array of dependencies. Most likely your directive should be retrieving the module by omitting the array: `angular.module("angularApp");`

Comment: @pankajparkar nope, the console is clean.

Comment: @SunilD. No, I'm just starting the app so the code you're seeing is the whole thing, minus a little of the html. There isn't any other angular code.

Comment: are you putting all of the html content into the directive? Leave the page container content <html> <body> </body> </html> outside of the directive.

Comment: @domitall no, the code inside the directive is just the divs and its content.

Comment: Is your directive JS in a separate JS file? If so, are you referencing it in index.html?

Comment: @nairys yes, I added the head of the document to my post so you can see the links too.

Comment: Just a hunch, but try adding `replace: true` to the directive. If that works, I bet there's some weird behavior with the parallax js and parent DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your directive in a div and see it if works. I.e. `<div hometab></div>`

Comment: No luck, doing that takes me from "html inserted but JS not working" to "no html inserted."

Answer (score 0):

i experienced this issue couple days ago,
what i to do to fix this is just set transclude to be true, and set replace to be true. in case your code, it will be like this.

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("angularApp", []);

    app.directive('hometab', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'hometab.html',
            transclude : true,
            replace : true
        };
    });
})();
```